# Two Markers on Google Map with only one function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a tiny form in which the user can enter a location by zip and street.

```
<form>
    <input  id="zipcode" placeholder="" type="tel" pattern="d*" />
    <input  id="street1" placeholder=""  />
</form>
```

In the JS I fire up the script when the input is left.

```
$("#street1")
.blur(function () {
    if ($("#street1")
        .val()
        .length != 0 && $("#zipcode")
            .val()
            .length != 0) {
        var body = $("html, body");
        body.stop()
            .animate({
                scrollTop: 350
            }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                var targetAddress = $("#zipcode")
                    .val() + "," + $("#street1")
                    .val();
                codeAddress(targetAddress);
            });
    }
});

function codeAddress(target) {
address = target;
geocoder2 = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder2.geocode({
    'address': address
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        homemarker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng()),
            map: map,
            icon: iconPosition,
            draggable: true,
            title: 'Fixed'
        });
    }
});
}
```

The map is centered on the right location, but not only one but two markers are set to the position. Can you help me with that issue?

Comment: Which values are you entering? It's not happening to me. See http://output.jsbin.com/xulemof (I entered `1` and `israel` to the inputs).

Comment: @MoshFeu on your example I entered "20095"  "Hamburg" and it happens again :) in Safari, Firefox and Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cause you bind event on both `html` and `body`.

Remove the comma `$("html, body")` would work as expected,

```
$("#street1")
.blur(function () {
    if ($("#street1")
        .val()
        .length != 0 && $("#zipcode")
            .val()
            .length != 0) {
        var body = $("html body"); // here
        body.stop()
            .animate({
                scrollTop: 350
            }, 500, 'swing', function () {
                var targetAddress = $("#zipcode")
                    .val() + "," + $("#street1")
                    .val();
                codeAddress(targetAddress);
            });
    }
});
```

Comment: Shame on me! Thanks a lot!